Migrating from Guice to spring load context.xml and bind to class
I have an old web application using google guice that i am trying to remove in favor of spring 6.
I have a class file that extends JerseyServletModule and in configureServlets()
I am getting the context file from tomcat conf directory. I would like to do this in spring instead.
Here is part of the class
public class MediaGuiceModule extends JerseyServletModule {

   @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {


   try {
            WebAppPropertiesProvider propertiesProvider = new WebAppPropertiesProvider(  getServletContext(), this.getClass().getClassLoader() );
            properties = propertiesProvider.loadProperties();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
          }


          Gallery gallery = GalleryFactory.buildGallery( countryCodes, properties );
        bind( Gallery.class ).toInstance( gallery );
  }

How would get the context.xml and bind it like in the above example? I am fairly new to spring.
I am unsure what classes to use to accomplish this. The only resource i found was to load it via classpath. Which isnt what i am needing. I do realize that i will need to remove MediaGuiceModule soon. Is there an interface i can use to create a class to achieve this? Any help is much appreciated because i dont think i am googling the right words. Thank you
